# Unable to configure RestyGWT sample application

Tags: resty-gwt

I want to run a sample GWT application. I am using Eclipse IDE. I had imported code from https://github.com/ronanquillevere/gwtrestapp. I want to run this application, but found a configuration error.

[image: variable preferences non-existing resource]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>